# My ResultSet is returning values but it is not storing values to string, why?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat6

I am a beginner to programming, i am requesting to be kind and also requesting you to notify me, if there is any other mistakes in my code.

This code was working fine yesterday, i had updated some values in database today and now it is not working. on debugging i found that the resultset is returning values but now it fails stored in the String that i declared

```
public int startpgm(String xyz) {

    int i=0;

    String sp       = null;

    String Sb_SWLat = null;
    String Sb_NELat = null;
    String Sb_SWLon = null;
    String Sb_NELon = null;

    String qrySb = "select SW_lat, SW_lon, NE_lat, NE_lon from tbl_zones where zone='south'";

    try {
        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet Sb=stmt.executeQuery(qrySb);
    if(Sb.next()){ 

        Sb_SWLat=Sb.getString("SW_lat");
        Sb_NELat=Sb.getString("NE_lat");
        Sb_SWLon=Sb.getString("SW_lon");            
        Sb_NELon=Sb.getString("NE_lon");

    }
    System.out.println("Sb_SWLat:"+Sb_SWLat);
    System.out.println("Sb_NELat:"+Sb_NELat);
    System.out.println("Sb_SWLon:"+Sb_SWLon);
    System.out.println("Sb_NELon:"+Sb_NELon);


    String qrysouth = "select priority from tbl_vcl where latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?";

    PreparedStatement pss = conn.prepareStatement(qrysouth);
    pss.setString(1, Sb_SWLat);
    pss.setString(2, Sb_NELat);
    pss.setString(3, Sb_SWLon);
    pss.setString(4, Sb_NELon);

    ResultSet rsSouth= pss.executeQuery();
    System.out.println("South ResultSet:"+rsSouth);

    if(rsSouth.next()){

    sp=rsSouth.getString("priority");
    System.out.println("South priority:"+sp);

    }   
    i=1;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
        return i ;
    }
```

And on executing program, This function is called from another page, my eclipse console:-

```
   Jan 18, 2016 6:35:58 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/53  config=null
Sb_SWLat: 9.993839
Sb_NELat: 9.994127
Sb_SWLon: 76.357213
Sb_NELon: 76.357329
Jan 18, 2016 6:35:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1018 ms
South ResultSet:com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@c4728f
```

When i tried the query by manually entering the values in mysql console:-

```
mysql> select sum(priority) from tbl_vcl where latitude >=9.993839 and latitude <=9.994127 and longitude >=76.357213 and longitude<=76.357329;
+---------------+
| sum(priority) |
+---------------+
|             3 |
+---------------+
```

`rsSouth != null` and why i am getting `sp=null` in which `sp=rsSouth.getString("sum(priority)")` ? I am requesting you to correct me, if there is any other mistakes in my program or other best method to improve efficiency. Thanks in Advance.

DDL of my table:

```
mysql> desc tbl_vcl;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| pk_vcl_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| vehicle_nm  | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| reg_nu      | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| officer_mob | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| active      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| updated_at  | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| latitude    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| longitude   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| priority    | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @all, the program looks long but my error is simple and specific. Please do not close this page by assuming this is something big!!

Comment: I had updated my code with "select sum(priority) as total" still same result :(

Comment: The priority is defined as int(2) in MySql database

Comment: Hello, I am still expecting a help! I spend my entire day on this. pelase....

Comment: Please provide the DDL of your table and sample data, along with the expected output. You may want to set up an example at http://www.sqlfiddle.com or the like.

Comment: And by the way, could you come up with a more concise version of your code. Just what really matters to reproduce the problem. - Also, the output you show does not match the code.

Comment: when i removed the "where latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?" from query it is working fine, i am able to get the 'priority'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example query, you have

`... where latitude >=9.993839 and ...`

This indicates that the fields in your table are of a *numeric* type. However, in your code, you use `getString()` to read the values and, more importantly, you use `pse.setString(1, Eb_SWLat);` to set the parameter values.

You should be using `getFloat()` and `setFloat()` instead, because MySQL will have a hard time trying to compare float columns with string parameters.

Comment: in my MySql, latitude and longitude is defined as varchar(20). So that is not the problem.

Comment: i did the modifications as you said.

Comment: when i removed the "where latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?" from query it is working fine, i am able to get the 'priority'

Comment: Found the solution by the end of the day. I changed the String to float and now it is working fine. Thank You :)

Comment: By the end of the day i realized the fact & every one should understand that String is not capable of handling location coordinates in JAVA. It doesnt matter how you defined the location column in your mysql. Use float in the java :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give alias for `sum(priority)`

```
String qrysouth = "select sum(priority) from tbl_vcl where  latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?";

PreparedStatement pss = conn.prepareStatement(qrysouth);
pss.setString(1, Sb_SWLat);
pss.setString(2, Sb_NELat);
pss.setString(3, Sb_SWLon);
pss.setString(4, Sb_NELon);

ResultSet rsSouth= pss.executeQuery();

if(rsSouth.next()){
    sp=String.valueOf(rsSouth.getLong(1););
    System.out.println("South priority:"+sp);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thought so too at first. However, `getString()` on a non-existing column should give an `SQLException` instead of returning `null`, which it doesn't in the OP's code.

Comment: @Anoop LL above method not working, value of sp is initiated as null in the program. So i tried printing it directly, and still it gives null for :-    'System.out.println("South priority:"+rsSouth.getString("total"));'

Comment: @MohamedAshref i have updated the answer just try this. Removed the alias and given rsSouth.getLong(1)

Comment: @Anoop LL now i am getting,  South priority:0  In MySql i have defined priority as int(2).

Comment: Then i tried, sp=String.valueOf(rsSouth.getInt(1)); still am getting result as 0

Comment: @MohamedAshref i tried by giving alias name its giving the sum

Comment: @ Anoop LL now i cant even get the 'priority'. i was getting sum(priority) yesterday. still am getting ResultSet ResultSet:com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@14af22

Comment: @MohamedAshref why are you trying to print ResultSet object??

Comment: @ Anoop LL it is part of a long code, so i just clipped the code which is not working. i need to get the value of 'sum(priority)' into a string

Comment: @Anoop LL when i removed the "where latitude >=? and latitude <=? and longitude >=? and longitude<=?" from query it is working fine, i am able to get the 'priority'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100982/discussion-between-anoop-ll-and-mohamed-ashref).

Comment: @Anoop LL Thank you for your support. I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to use alias field names as below

```
select sum(priority) as total .....
```

Comment: still returning null